# How to automatically split one row into different rows in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, transpose, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I'm trying to split one row in Google Sheets into different rows depending on its content. Here's an example:

```
Name    | Ticker | Categories
Bitcoin | BTC    | currency; store-of-value; trust layer; smart contracts; cross-industry
Ripple  | XRP    | currency; cross-industry
```

Into:

```
Name    | Ticker | Categories
Bitcoin | BTC    | currency 
Bitcoin | BTC    | store-of-value 
Bitcoin | BTC    | trust layer
Bitcoin | BTC    | smart contracts 
Bitcoin | BTC    | cross industry
Ripple  | XRP    | currency
Ripple  | XRP    | cross-industry
```

How can I do this using a script or any other tools?

Comment: you want to preserve those `;` ??

Comment: No, edited it already. Thank you @player0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(C1:C, ";"))<>"", "♥"&A1:A&"♦"&B1:B&"♦"&
 IFERROR(SPLIT(C1:C, ";")), )),,999^99)),,999^99), "♥")), "♦")))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you @player0, just one question: what is the use of the shapes?

Comment: just a separation delimiter for SPLIT. it has no meaning. you can use any symbol you wish but it should be unique

Comment: Another question: what is 999^99 for?

Comment: also nothing :) just a rly big number so the query would process that much rows (in theory)