# Split Google Sheets Query results from one row into two

Tags: google-sheets, transpose, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I want to take my `QUERY` results and move one cell (H [description]) to the following row of each result.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56420002/how-to-automatically-split-one-row-into-different-rows-in-google-sheets), which is very close, but the format of the table is different, so I'm not sure how to apply it to my scenario.

This is the basic idea:

```
    Category | Sub-Category | Item       | Description
    Fruit    | Citrus       | Orange     | It's orange
    Fruit    | Melon        | Cantaloupe | Round
```

Into

```
    Category | Sub-Category | Item  
    Fruit    | Citrus       | Orange     
    It's orange
    Fruit    | Melon        | Cantaloupe 
    Round
```

Answer (score 1):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(C1:C, ";"))<>"", "♥"&A1:A&"♦"&B1:B&"♦"&
 IFERROR(SPLIT(C1:C, ";"))&"♥"&D1:D, )),,999^99)),,999^99), "♥")), "♦")), D1, ), 
 "where Col1 is not null", 0))
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(C1:C<>"", "♥"&A1:A&"♦"&B1:B&"♦"&C1:C&"♥ ♦"&D1:D, ))
 ,,999^99)),,999^99), "♥")), "♦")), D1, ), 
 "where Col2 is not Null", 0))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: That's great!  Thank you!  So, do I just need to add `&C2:C&"♦"` and replace the column value to expand the table?

Comment: not sure where &C2:C&"♦"  comes from... not from image

Comment: Well, that didn't really work.  [Here's the formula](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Za3a9d3hKJCMAxy72sIRH9L61wLwvBw02Fwj_9E_z-4/edit#gid=1890007751&range=A15)

Comment: I have tried everything I can think of to offset "it's orange" one (or whatever) columns, but can't seem to accomplish it.  Is that a quick modification, or does the whole formula need to be rewritten for that to happen?

Comment: you mean like "its orange" and "round" to be in G column instead of F column?

Comment: Yes. Offset it by one column.