# Offset column 2 of query results by one row

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, transpose, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I'm trying to create a list of results from a `QUERY` where the result from column 1 acts as a "title" in column 1 and then the result from column 2 would be displayed on the following row, but still in the second column.  And this would be the pattern for all results.
I've attempted using the `OFFSET` function. I have also attempted `OFFSET` within `QUERY` but just can't seem to get what I'm looking for.

This is where I left off...

```excel
=ArrayFormula(SORT(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(F2:F,QUERY({J2:K},"SELECT Col1,Col2 WHERE Col1 matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, F2:F)&"'",0),{1,2},)),1,TRUE))
```

Ultimately, it would look like

```
Title
  Description
Title 2
  Description 2
```

[Here is my sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rf1-gxIyNAunJjwtm9NnEcAp6-rz735n8vtmIMb6Ulc/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Hello, have you considered doing this with Apps Script?

Comment: No @Jescanellas, I hadn't.  I suppose I could and that would probably be easier, but I already have a lot of onEdit functions going on my sheet.  I just assumed a formula would be faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFNA(
 VLOOKUP(SORT(F2:F), {J2:K4, "♦"&J2:J4, "♦♣ ♣"&K2:K4}, {3, 4}, 0)))
 ,,99^99)),,99^99), "♦")), "♣"))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer! The only other thing I was hoping for is that the second line be offset into column B.  Much like you did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56573111/split-google-sheets-query-results-from-one-row-into-two)