# How to have one cell show amount of times a value appears within a range while considering dates next to those specified Columns?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, formula

In my sheet1 column N & starting in row 3 I have a list of areas represented by numbers, next to each number on column O I have the amount of times those areas have been worked on as found in a specified range (columns between A-L, rows 3-17. I am using the COUNTIF formula, but that alone formulates amount of times a value is found.

I'm wandering if a script can be used to have it consider the date next to it so that the ouptut shows only areas worked on in past 6 months. I'm attaching a picture to show my sheet. Thanks beforehand for any help given!

Example: Column A = list of numbers, Column B = list of dates,  C1 = Amount of times "1" is found in past 30 days.

[Sheet1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAI0s.png)

Comment: Please consider providing what you tried until now, and clearly indicate what is the desired output. Consider providing a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on (free of sensitive information), not just a screenshot.

Comment: do you want a formula or script for this one?

Comment: A script will likely be needed since desired output should show amount of times a number appears in columnA but considering date in columnB. Potentially using -> if (dataday == today-180) & something like the MATCH function used here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29972016/is-there-a-faster-countif

Comment: I've currently created a sample formula but wasn't able to take into consideration the C1. Is the C1 needed? aside from that, the formula is working for the output you want to have

Comment: C1 in example represents what I have in screenshot starting in ColumnN. Thats where I'm using "Countif" to find how many times a number is found within a range. Im open to different ideas.

Comment: ahh. I now get it. this should be plausible in formula alone. What you will need is countifs() for counting the cells, offset() for getting the right area for the quantity part, and today() under countifs() to compute for the last 6 months condition which should be the same as you mentioned in the previous comment. offset is just optional, but it will make your formula dynamic when copied to multiple cells

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this formula to count your quantity per area-date checking:

=COUNTIFS($B$2:$D$11,">="&TODAY()-180,$B$2:$D$11,"<="&TODAY(),$A$2:$C$11,"="&OFFSET(F2,0,-1))

What this formula does is to first, get the rows and columns corresponding to the Date(B2:D11). Date values from B2:D11 are being compared to the date today minus 180 days(corresponding to 6 months), and also, checking the date if it is an advance date, so it will not increment the quantity if it is not within the 6 months range prior to the date today.

For the Area values from A2:C11, these are being compared to the values of Area in E2 column.

Refer to this image for my sample spreadsheet:

[Area-Date Quantity Counting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aE6H6.png)

Comment: Nice job, Monique!  Welcome here.  Did you know that you can paste your image directly into your answer?  Makes it a bit easier to use.  See here for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56420002/how-to-automatically-split-one-row-into-different-rows-in-google-sheets/56420066#56420066  And it is preferred to format your formula as a code block, using the formatting options above the answer block.  Have fun!